# Issues of the subreport when added  to main report

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have report that contains a subreport,the reports in the main are created dynamicaly depending on the parameter values,i have a subreport  that contain textboxs,the problem with this  subreport  when add to the main report that is  shown on a given parameter and it collapse on other!!!,knowing that when this subreport is empty(the dataset return no rows) is shown on a parameter and on other parameter is hide............i need this subreport to be shown even if empty and not to collapse

Comment: I am not certain but it appears maybe one of the parameters on the sub report needs to be changed to accept NULL as a value.  I believe the default is a nested report won't be shown if it does not find the value of something.  You could force it to show in theory by accepting a null.  I have never tried this though so it is just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wish to keep show the subreport's textboxs even if you get no values from the main report parameters, I suggest you to :

Create a table in the sub report , and delete the rows (keep just the header), then use it as a textbox (because in this case you can link a dataset directly to the table in the table properties).

Next, in the table cell enter the following expression

`=iif(RowNumber(Nothing) < 1, " ", Field!yourData.Value)` - that way you table will always have a value and the subreport will not collapse